# Why is this query returning unwanted results?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, pivot

Good morning,

I have a problem with this query:

```
SELECT  
    P.txt_nome AS Pergunta,   
    IP.nome AS Resposta,   
    COUNT(*) AS Qtd   
FROM  
    tb_resposta_formulario RF   
    INNER JOIN formularios F ON  
        F.id_formulario = RF.id_formulario   
    INNER JOIN tb_pergunta P ON  
        P.id_pergunta = RF.id_pergunta   
    INNER JOIN tb_resposta_formulario_combo RFC ON  
        RFC.id_resposta_formulario = RF.id_resposta_formulario   
    INNER JOIN itens_perguntas IP ON  
        IP.id_item_pergunta = RFC.id_item_pergunta   
WHERE  
    RF.id_formulario = 2   
GROUP BY    
    P.txt_nome,   
    IP.nome
```

This is the actual result of this query:

|Pergunta| Resposta |Qtd|
|Produto |Combo 1MB | 3 |
|Produto |Combo 2MB | 5 |
|Produto |Combo 4MB | 1 |
|Produto |Combo 6MB | 1 |
|Produto |Combo 8MB | 4 |
|Região  |MG        | 3 |
|Região  |PR        | 2 |
|Região  |RJ        | 3 |
|Região  |SC        | 1 |
|Região  |SP        | 5 |

These are the results I was expecting:

|Produto   | Região  |Qtd|
|Combo 1MB | MG      | 3 |
|Combo 2MB | SP      | 5 |
|Combo 4MB | SC      | 1 |
|Combo 6MB | RJ      | 1 |
|Combo 8MB | PR      | 2 |

I am using the PIVOT and UNPIVOT operators but the result is not satisfactory.

Has anyone already faced this situation before? Do you have any insight you can offer?

I already analyzed these links:

- [SQL Server 2005 Pivot on Unknown Number of Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213702/sql-server-2005-pivot-on-unknown-number-of-columns)
- [Transpose a set of rows as columns in SQL Server 2000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152770/transpose-a-set-of-rows-as-columns-in-sql-server-2000)
- [SQL Server 2005, turn columns into rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428041/sql-server-2005-turn-columns-into-rows)
- [Pivot Table and Concatenate Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159456/pivot-table-and-concatenate-columns-sql-problem#159803)
- [PIVOT in sql 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198716/pivot-in-sql-2005#199763)

Att,
Pelegrini

Answer (score 2):

The "obvious" answer is: because the query is incorrect. We really know nothing about the table structure and what you're trying to achieve.

Concerning at least one very basic problem in your query: you're expecting the columns `|Produto | Região |Qtd|` in your response, yet the query unambiguously selects the columns `Pergunta`, `Reposta` and `Qtd`, which coincides with the result you're getting.

How well are you acquainted with SQL at all? It may be worth it to read an introductory text. I'd suggest [this](http://philip.greenspun.com/sql/) as a good introduction. (Uses Oracle, but the principles are the same)