# Is there a quick way to populate array from DB with record id?

Tags: php, arrays, data-binding, php-5.4

(Simplification)
I have a table `[id][username]`
Would like when I fetch all from table **NOT TO GET**

```
[
0=>[10,'unam1'],
1=>[20,'unam2'], ...
]
```

but rather use the record ID as the array key. Is there a way in php5.4? I use PDO.

```
[
10=>[10,'unam1'],
20=>[20,'unam2'], ...
]
```

OR

```
[
10=>['unam1'],
20=>['unam2'], ...
]
```

Comment: I think this answer will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15528833/2816475

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDO associative arrays - return associative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512861/pdo-associative-arrays-return-associative)

Comment: This way you two suggest is using PHP to format the array, I am familiar with such ways. I am wondering if PHP has a native function for that very common need.

Comment: Maybe using `PDOStatement::fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP)` will return similar result. It will group records by the first column. More information here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php